# C POSIX thread's mutex/condition working differently depending on where variable lives

Tags: c, multithreading, posix, mutex

I am seeing unexpected behavior for mutexes/conditions in C POSIX threads depending on whether the mutex and condition variables are set in the global scope (which works) on in a struct (which sometimes works).

I programming on a Mac and then running the same code on a Linux machine. I copied the code from this example, which works as expected in both machines: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fapis%2Fusers_73.htm
This example has the `pthread_mutex_t` and `pthread_cond_t` in the global scope:

```
pthread_cond_t      cond  = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t     mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
...
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
...
```

However if I change this to store the cond and mutex in a struct, it works on the Mac but does *not* work on Linux.

Here is an overview of the changes I made:

```
typedef struct _test_data_t {
  pthread_mutex_t cond;
  pthread_cond_t mutex;
} test_data_t;
...
pthread_mutex_lock(&(test_data->mutex));
...
```

Here is the output I get on Mac (which works)

```
Create 5 threads
Thread blocked
Thread blocked
Thread blocked
Thread blocked
Thread blocked
Wake up all waiting threads...
Wait for threads and cleanup
Main completed
```

Here is the output on Linux (which does not work)

```
Create 5 threads
Thread blocked // Hangs here forever, other threads can't lock mutex
```

Does anyone know why this might be happening? I will admit that I am not a C expert so I don't know what could have happened in the switch from using a global variable to a struct variable.

Thanks in advance for your help.

---

Here is the code (with some error checking stripped out for brevity):

```
typedef struct _test_data_t {
  int conditionMet;
  pthread_mutex_t cond;
  pthread_cond_t mutex;
} test_data_t;

void *threadfunc(void *parm)
{
  int           rc;
  test_data_t *test_data = (test_data_t *) parm;

  rc = pthread_mutex_lock((pthread_mutex_t *)&(test_data->mutex));

  while (!test_data->conditionMet) {
    printf("Thread blocked\n");
    rc = pthread_cond_wait(&test_data->cond, &test_data->mutex);
  }

  rc = pthread_mutex_unlock(&test_data->mutex);
  return NULL;
}

void runThreadTest() {

  int NTHREADS = 5;

  int                   rc=0;
  int                   i;

  // Initialize mutex/condition.
  test_data_t test_data;
  test_data.conditionMet = 0;
  rc = pthread_mutex_init(&test_data.mutex, NULL);
  rc = pthread_cond_init(&test_data.cond, NULL);

  // Create threads.
  pthread_t             threadid[NTHREADS];

  printf("Create %d threads\n", NTHREADS);
  for(i=0; i<NTHREADS; ++i) {
    rc = pthread_create(&threadid[i], NULL, threadfunc, &test_data);
  }

  sleep(5);
  rc = pthread_mutex_lock(&test_data.mutex);

  /* The condition has occurred. Set the flag and wake up any waiting threads */
  test_data.conditionMet = 1;
  printf("Wake up all waiting threads...\n");
  rc = pthread_cond_broadcast(&test_data.cond);

  rc = pthread_mutex_unlock(&test_data.mutex);

  printf("Wait for threads and cleanup\n");
  for (i=0; i<NTHREADS; ++i) {
    rc = pthread_join(threadid[i], NULL);
  }

  pthread_cond_destroy(&test_data.cond);
  pthread_mutex_destroy(&test_data.mutex);

  printf("Main completed\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the member named `mutex` is a `pthread_cond_t` and the member named `cond` is a `pthread_mutex_t`. Casts that should be unnecessary may be hiding that fact.

```
typedef struct _test_data_t {
  int conditionMet;
  pthread_mutex_t cond; // <-- poorly named
  pthread_cond_t mutex; // <-- poorly named
} test_data_t;
```

This line in the thread function should not need a cast:

```
  rc = pthread_mutex_lock((pthread_mutex_t *)&(test_data->mutex));
```

However, you have several calls that don't have the cast (so the compiler should be complaining loudly on those).  I'm beginning to think this might be a typo that's a red herring.

Comment: Wow, nice catch! I'm surprised the type system didn't prevent that.

Comment: It would have if it hadn't been explicitly overridden.

Comment: Oh geez, how embarrassing, that was definitely it. I'm surprised it worked on my Mac at all. Thanks!

Comment: @something_or_nothing: happens to everyone sometime or another, and it's the kind of thing only someone else will ever notice.  I'm more curious about why the calls that don't use casts aren't failing to compile?

Comment: There were warnings but I ignored them, guess I should have paid more attention to them. My inexperience in C let me to believe many warnings I see could be safely ignored, which I guess is not true

Comment: @something_or_nothing: A common problem with warnings is that there is a lot of code where they are ignored (and often safely). If you join a new project, there will often be warnings that you're just supposed to ignore. But for new code, you should try to understand any new warnings and modify the new code to get rid of them. Only use a cast to silence a warning if you really understand what's going on. In any case, I'm still surprised that these weren't outright errors.